# I'm rather flexible, how should I stretch my hamstrings?

Tags: stretching, flexibility, hamstring

When I'm standing I can have my hands flat on the floor and not feel much of a stretch in my hamstrings.

Currently I've been lying on my back, and with one leg straight out in front, pull the other leg over my head. This works but I'm curious if there are other techniques?

Thanks,
Amy

Comment: If you are already that flexible, do you *need* to stretch even more?

Comment: you are describing what sounds like a static stretch and it sounds very much like your hamstrings are flexible enough 

unless you're competing in some sport that requires hyper extendibility, this kind of stretch is not required.

Answer (score 3):

It appears you are flexible enough and your hamstrings don't need additional stretching.

I would focus on strengthening your hamstrings instead of stretching. Add deadlifts or other hamstring exercises you prefer to your fitness routine at the gym.

Too much flexibility can be a cause of injury.

Answer (score 2):

If you round your back when bending over and touching the ground, you're taking the hamstrings out of the equation. Try keeping a flat back and hinging forward at the waist.